# Enumerate SpecialFolders Enum

Tags: powershell, enums

I have successfully used `[environment]::getfolderpath('SPECIALFOLDERNAME')` to get the path of a special folder, but now I want to somewhat reverse that.
I want to start with `C:\Users\Px_Install\Documents`, which is what `[environment]::getfolderpath('mydocuments')` would return, and get $true back. If I start with `C:\SomeRandomFolder` I want a $false back.

Given that `[System.Enum]::GetNames([System.DayOfWeek])` works, I thought I could use `[System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Environment.SpecialFolder])` or perhaps `[System.Environment.SpecialFolder]::GetNames()` to then loop through all available special folders and test against my path. But that failed with

> Unable to find type [System.Environment.SpecialFolder].

And it's a bit brute force anyway. So, is there a more direct route, and if not what am I doing wrong with my enumeration of the SpecialFolder Enum?

EDIT: On the second question, I just found this works.

```
[enum]::GetNames([Environment+SpecialFolder])
```

But a less brute force solution than a loop would be grand.

For a little context, I am working on deleting empty folders inverse recursively, i.e. I delete an empty folder, then check to see if the parent folder is now empty, delete it if so, and work back up the tree. However, I want to stop once I hit any kind of system folder, a perfect example being My Documents. Even if there is nothing else in My Documents, I want to leave it alone.

Comment: Maybe `$SpecialFolderS = [System.Enum]::GetValues([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]) | ForEach-Object {[environment]::getfolderpath($_)}`?

Comment: @josefZ That's pretty close to what I am doing now. I expand the For loop to be more script appropriate, meaning more readable when I come back to the code in a year. I thought perhaps there was a IsSystemFolder method or some such. But I have tried this and it is very fast, so I think it will work.

Comment: `$SpecialFolderS | Get-item -ea 0 | Select-Object Mode, Attributes, FullName` shows **System** attribute in the `Attributes` property, or as the 4th character (zero-based)  in the `Mode` string…